# Can I run dataflowjob between projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I want to export data from Cloud Spanner in project A to GCS in project B as AVRO.
If my service-account in project B is given spanner.read access in project A, can I run a dataflow-job from project B with template: Cloud_Spanner_to_GCS_Avro and write to GCS in project B?

I've tried both in console and with following command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run my_job_name 
--gcs-location='gs://dataflow-emplates/latest/Cloud_Spanner_to_GCS_Avro' 
--region=my_region 
--parameters='instanceId=name_of_instance,databaseId=databaseid,outputDir=my_bucket_url 
--service-account-email=my_serviceaccount_email
```

I'm not sure how to specify projectId of the Spanner instance. 
With this command from project B it looks in project B:s Spanner and cannot find the instance and database.

I've tried to set: instanceId=projects/id_of_project_A/instances/
name_of_instance but it's not a valid input

Comment: It should work. Try it.

Comment: I've tried, but got stuck on how to specify the path to project A:s Spanner database,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer seems to be that it's possible for some templates or if you write a custom one, but not the template I want to use, batch export from Spanner to GCS Avro files. 
And that it might be added in a future update to the template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you have to grant the correct authorization on the [dataflow service account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#controller_service_account)

I recommend you to use a "user-managed service account". The default one is the Compute Engine default service account with the `editor` roles on the host project, too many authorizations....

Comment: Ok, thanks, then I know it's possible. How do I specify the path to Spanner instance in project A. I've tried this without success: gcloud dataflow jobs run my_name --gcs-location='gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Cloud_Spanner_to_GCS_Avro' --region=my_region  --parameters='instanceId=projects/id_of_project_A/instances/name_of_instance,databaseId=databaseid,outputDir=my_bucket_url --service-account-email=my_serviceaccount_email

Comment: Have a try by adding this parameters `--parameters='instanceId=name_of_instance,databaseId=databaseid,outputDir=my_bucket_url,spannerProjectId=id_of_project_A`. By [looking at the code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportPipeline.java#L78), I think there is an undocumented parameter

Comment: Yes, I get this error: parameterViolations:
  - description: Unrecognized parameter
    parameter: spannerProjectId

Comment: It looks like spannerProjectId was added after the latest template release. It should be included in the next release.